# npm error: Failed at the sodium@3.0.2 preinstall script

Tags: npm, npm-install

i get:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sodium@3.0.2 preinstall: `node install.js --preinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sodium@3.0.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

when trying to run "npm install"
why is this? i tried looking at other threads and nothing works for me.

Comment: Did you try  node version 8?

Comment: Probably, i will try downloading it again.